# Unable to open JPEG files with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am serving a static page with assets. Unfortunately i am not able to open images, whereas JS and CSS files are going through quite fine.

I simply receive `403 (Forbidden)` when trying attempting to access the files.

Directory hiarachy:

```
/var/www/servers/new.test.com
    index.html
    static/
        img/
        css/
        js/
```

Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name area1.test.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/new_test.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/new_test.error.log;
    root /var/www/servers/new.test.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;   
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires 1m;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 1m;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

}
```

Please ignore the expire durations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permissions on the files don't allow the web server to read the files. Most likely the owner / group of the files does not match the web server user / group, and other people are not allowed to read the files.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and for me, it was SELinux permissions.  Fixed with...

```
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/problematic/file(s)
```